# Function to return a Haskell record with a modified field

Tags: haskell, syntax, record

**Given**:

```
data MyRecord a = MyRecord{list :: [a], other_fields :: Char, …}
```

I am trying to write a function which puts a new `a` on list and returns a new `MyRecord`:

```
pushOntoList :: a -> MyRecord -> MyRecord
```

**Question**:

Is there a way to write `pushOntoList` is such a way that it does not depend on what is in the rest of the record, but simply gives it back unmodified?

Another way to ask this is can you write `pushOntoList` without seeing the rest of the `MyRecord` definition?

Comment: If you are doing anything the slightest bit nontrivial with record fields, I suggest looking into fclabels or data-accessor to give you composable record accessors. Haskell's records are totally ugly and nerfed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, very easily using the record accessor/label syntax:

```
b = a { list = 'x' : list a }
```

as in the function:

```
pushOntoList c a = a { list = c : list a }
```

e.g.

```
data MyRecord a = MyRecord {list :: [a], other_fields :: Char}
    deriving Show

main = do
    let a = MyRecord [] 'x'
        b = a { list = 'x' : list a }
    return (a,b)
```

Comment: Yes, that was easy.  I would like to point out in my own defense that the syntax simply does not appear anywhere in [Learn You Some Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses), [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html) or [A Gentle Introduction to Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/moretypes.html).

Comment: Oh, record syntax is indeed a somewhat obscure and slightly hairy part of the language. And don't even get me started on [the syntactic extensions](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-puns).

Comment: The syntax appears in RWH chapter 10.

Comment: It was a little hard to find, so [here's a direct link to the part in chapter 10](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/code-case-study-parsing-a-binary-data-format.html#Parse.hs:modifyOffset).